# MP Chart Showing One Extra Value at X_axis in Line Chart?

Tags: java, android, charts

I have Implemented MP LineChart. Every thing is working except one.it adds first month at the end of x axis. and values starts from second point not first one. i tried several solutions provided on google but couldn't succeeded.
e.g in following screen shot my months list contains [apr,may,jun,jul,aug] but its adding in extra apr at the end and line is starting from may not apr.
following is my code.

```
  String[] mMonths;
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_multi_line_chart);
    context = this;
    mpref = new MySharedPreferences(this);
    charts_list = new ArrayList<Charts_Data_Model>();
    mChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart1);
    mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);

    mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    mChart.setDescription("VSC CHART");
    mChart.setDrawBorders(false);

    mChart.getAxisLeft().setEnabled(true);
    mChart.getAxisRight().setDrawAxisLine(false);
    mChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
    mChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
    mChart.getXAxis().setDrawAxisLine(true);
    mChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(true);

    // enable touch gestures
    mChart.setTouchEnabled(true);

    // enable scaling and dragging
    mChart.setDragEnabled(true);
    mChart.setScaleEnabled(true);

    // if disabled, scaling can be done on x- and y-axis separately
    mChart.setPinchZoom(true);


    Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
    l.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.ABOVE_CHART_LEFT);
    l.setXEntrySpace(7f);
    l.setYEntrySpace(0f);
    l.setYOffset(0f);
    l.setDirection(Legend.LegendDirection.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    l.setWordWrapEnabled(true);


    new Task4().execute();

   }


    class Task4 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MultiLineChartActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("please wait");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {


        getChartDataHadsM();


        //Record method
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);
        XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.setAxisMinValue(0f);
        xAxis.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);
        // xAxis.setGranularityEnabled(false);
        xAxis.setGranularity(1f);

        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new AxisValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
                return mMonths[(int) value % mMonths.length];
            }

            @Override
            public int getDecimalDigits() {
                return 0;
            }
        });


        LineData data = new LineData(sets);
        mChart.setData(data);
        mChart.invalidate();
        pDialog.dismiss();

    }
}

   public void getChartDataHadsM() {
    mMonths = new String[charts_list_HadsM.size()];
    ArrayList<Entry> e1 = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    ArrayList<Entry> e2 = new ArrayList<Entry>();

    int size = charts_list_HadsM.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        String month = charts_list_HadsM.get(i).month;
        mMonths[i] = month;
        String anx = charts_list_HadsM.get(i).anx;
        String dep = charts_list_HadsM.get(i).dep;

        e1.add(new Entry(i + 1, Integer.parseInt(anx)));
        e2.add(new Entry(i + 1, Integer.parseInt(dep)));


    }
    sets = new ArrayList<ILineDataSet>();
    if (!e1.isEmpty()) {
        LineDataSet d1 = new LineDataSet(e1, "anxiety");
        d1.setLineWidth(2.5f);
        d1.setCircleRadius(4.5f);
        d1.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(244, 117, 117));
        d1.setDrawValues(false);
        sets.add(d1);
    }
    if (!e2.isEmpty()) {
        LineDataSet d2 = new LineDataSet(e2, "depression");
        d2.setLineWidth(2.5f);
        d2.setCircleRadius(4.5f);
        d2.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(244, 117, 117));
        d2.setColor(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS[0]);
        d2.setCircleColor(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS[0]);
        d2.setDrawValues(false);
        sets.add(d2);
    }


}
```

[image: Screen Shot of my line chart]

Please Any Hint or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not been working with the chartset you use. But the error you are describing and the image look like you are messing the indexes.

I have reviewed the source and I found the following thing that I find suspicious and you may want to check:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
// your month list is 0-based
    String month = charts_list_HadsM.get(i).month;
    mMonths[i] = month;
    String anx = charts_list_HadsM.get(i).anx;
    String dep = charts_list_HadsM.get(i).dep;


// Your data list is 1-based
// You add the data at (i+1) effectively skipping position 0
    e1.add(new Entry(i + 1, Integer.parseInt(anx)));
    e2.add(new Entry(i + 1, Integer.parseInt(dep)));


}
```

Essentially, your month have now one legend too few, and it seems that the legend rotates when it reaches the end of entries.

It matches your image:

In APR column, there is no value, it starts with MAY. Then the values are added but there is one more value than there are month in the legend. Thus, the legend restarts with APR to show the extra value.

I suggest this fix:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
// your month list is 0-based
    String month = charts_list_HadsM.get(i).month;
    mMonths[i] = month;
    String anx = charts_list_HadsM.get(i).anx;
    String dep = charts_list_HadsM.get(i).dep;


// Make entries index 0-based, too
    e1.add(new Entry(i, Integer.parseInt(anx)));
    e2.add(new Entry(i, Integer.parseInt(dep)));
}
```